# ng-selected not working on option element with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select

I am using a `select` combobox with dynamic values from an OData response. Beccause of this I need to identify the 'highest' existing period in my response and set the `selected`attribute for the relevant `option` item.

This `select`is used as a period filter. That's why I also added an entry for 'all' periods. This can be removed in the sample and makes no difference in the behaviour.

Angular seems to evaluate the conditions etc. correct, so the element which should be selected gets the attribute `selected="selected"` and `ng-select="true"`.

Nevertheless the browser selects '' by default rather than the selected element. Even if I remove the option for all periods, the browser takes the 'empty' element and not the element with the `selected`attribute.

I checked other answer so similiar questions, but none of them worked and many reference `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`.

### More information

I am using AngularJS v1.4.9 and Chrome 48.0.2564.103 m

I am using a rather large OData response in JSON format as data source, so I'd need to rewrite the code here to provide an executable example.
I'll do this if it's necesary or required.

For other reasons, which I don't want to discuss here I cannot use `ng-options`, so please don't suggest this.

### HTML snippet - *commented and indented afterwards*

The other logic for sorting, ordering etc. is working fine.

```html
  <select class="semester-selection" ng-model="selectedPeriod.Period_Nav.PeriodName">

  <!-- This 'empty' option can be removed. ng-selected won't work then either -->
  <option ng-selected="false" value="">&lt;Alle&gt;</option>

  <option ng-selected="{{examResult.Period == getHighestPeriod()}}"
          ng-repeat="examResult in examResultData.results | uniquePeriod:'Period' | orderBy:'-Period'"
     value="{{examResult.Period_Nav.PeriodName}}">

        <!-- Debug information -->
{{examResult.Period_Nav.PeriodName}}
{{examResult.Period == getHighestPeriod()}}
{{getHighestPeriod()}}
  </option>

</select>
```

### Generated HTML via Angular JS

The generated code looks okay, because `selected="selected"` and `ng-select="true"` as in there for the desired element.

```html
<select class="semester-selection ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
        ng-model="selectedPeriod.Period_Nav.PeriodName">
  <option value="">&lt;Alle&gt;</option>
  
  <!-- ngRepeat: examResult in examResultData.results | uniquePeriod:'Period' | orderBy:'-Period' -->
  <option selected="selected" ng-selected="true" ng-repeat="examResult in examResultData.results | uniquePeriod:'Period' | orderBy:'-Period'" value="WiSe 2011/12" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    WiSe 2011/12
 true
 15014000
  </option>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: examResult in examResultData.results | uniquePeriod:'Period' | orderBy:'-Period' -->
  
  <option ng-selected="false" ng-repeat="examResult in examResultData.results | uniquePeriod:'Period' | orderBy:'-Period'" value="SoSe 2007" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
 SoSe 2007
 false
        15014000
  </option><!-- end ngRepeat: examResult in examResultData.results | uniquePeriod:'Period' | orderBy:'-Period' -->
</select>
```

### Result in the browser

When I open the page in the browser the combobox has still not the `selected` value as active, but the first or empty one.

[image: <Alle> was selected by default]

### Reduced sample for testing / fiddling around

Oh. This reduced sample works, so I need to find the issue somewhere else in the code.

```js
var app = angular.module('ExamResultList', [ ]);

app.controller('ExamResultController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  
  // Simplified sample data -> this can contain 'duplicates'
  $scope.examResultData = [
    {PeriodName:'WiSe 15/16', Period:8}, // fake OData OrderBy -> Highest period is the first elem
    {PeriodName:'SoSe 12',    Period:1},
    {PeriodName:'WiSe 12/13', Period:2},
    {PeriodName:'WiSe 12/13', Period:2},
    {PeriodName:'WiSe 12/13', Period:2},
    {PeriodName:'SoSe 13',    Period:3},
    {PeriodName:'WiSe 13/14', Period:4},
    {PeriodName:'SoSe 14',    Period:5},
    {PeriodName:'WiSe 14/15', Period:6},
    {PeriodName:'SoSe 15',    Period:7}
  ];
  
  $scope.highestPeriod = 0;
  
  $scope.getHighestPeriod = function() {
    // first element has the highest period, because the OData request has a orderby expression
    return $scope.examResultData[0].Period;
  };
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExamResultList" id="examResultListWrapper">
 <div ng-controller="ExamResultController as ExamResCtrl" id="examResultList">

  <select class="semester-selection">
   <option ng-selected="false" value="">&lt;Alle&gt;</option>
   <option ng-selected="{{examResult.Period == getHighestPeriod()}}"
     ng-repeat="examResult in examResultData"
     value="{{examResult.PeriodName}}">
    {{examResult.PeriodName}}
    
                <!-- Debug info
                {{examResult.Period == getHighestPeriod()}}
    {{getHighestPeriod()}}
                -->
   </option>
  </select>
      
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Use `ngOptions` - not an `ngRepeat` over an `option` element

Comment: @tymeJV Please read the whole question: *For other reasons, which I don't want to discuss here I cannot use ng-options, so please don't suggest this.*

Comment: Hey - any chance you can fiddle that?  I hate to provide an off-the-cuff answer to a complex question, but I'm wondering if you have to specify ng-value for the option items instead of just "value" in order for this to work.  I could test that theory with a fiddle.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @edencorbin Sorry, my priorities were shifted to other projects. I haven't been working on this issue for over a year now. You may want to try a newer Angular version or the solution posted below.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-selected` does not take expression brackets. Use

> ng-selected="examResult.Period == getHighestPeriod()"